# AngularJS: how to filter by two expressions with $filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Here's the $fiter documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

I accomplish what I need with the following:

```
$scope.images = $filter('filter')(imageList, { type: 'snapshot' });
$scope.images = $filter('filter')($scope.images, { status: 'ACTIVE' });
```

But I would like to refactor and simplify the code, preferably using one line of code instead of two.

I have looked around and some people suggest using a custom filter. Is there a way to accomplish it by using $filter out of the box?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't look like the code you have can be condensed much farther, it's already pretty terse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can combine both in one line like this:

```
$scope.images = $filter('filter')(imageList, { type: 'snapshot', status: 'ACTIVE' });
```